# Function expected _spFormOnSubmitWrapper

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server

I have overridden SharePoint ribbon save function using `_spFormOnSubmitWrapper()` on my js code.

I am getting

> "SCRIPT5002: function expected"

error when I try to check in page when debugger window is open in IE.

Click event of check in dialog ok button:

```
//check in dialog ok button
$(document).on("click", "#statechangedialog_okbutton", function () {
    _spFormOnSubmitWrapper = false;
    $('[id$=btnPageOk]').click();
});
```

**Error**:

[image]

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are overriding Save operation. It will cause conflict when Save is performed via Browser.

Update the script via SharePoint designer instead.